# What is the difference between the 'namespace' and the 'using' keywords in C#?

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

I'm new to C# and I don't fully understand what a **namespace** is, and what the **using**-keyword does. I'd appreciate it if someone could explain the difference. From my guess, `using` is similar to `#include` in C++.

If that's the case, what is a namespace for? The only exposure I've had to namespaces in C++, was when using `using namespace std;`, which just allowed me to forgo the `std::` in my function calls.

Comment: It also allowed you to pollute your namespace.

Comment: bparikh, you didn't think to look online first? like this just smells of extremely lazy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is of the most basic level of understanding, its more than well documented. please consider searching before you ask

Comment: The closest thing to `#include` in C# is a compiler command line option to add a reference: [`-reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option)

Comment: namespace - It is a collection of classes. We can call it a module. Although it is not compulsory to put class in a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The `namespace`-*statement* declares a namespace of your own; A set of "bundled classes" if you like. You can have very different classes in a name space, and you can also create sub-namespaces.

Using the `namespace` statement will therefor, implicitly make sure you can access other classes in the same **namespace**. You do not need to make explicit references within the same namespace.

Read [more on namespaces in C# here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace).

The `using` *directive* is used to use a namespace in your code, without explicitly referencing to a namespace. This is of course useful when using a namespace more than once in a class. The directive does not change the state or status of the class, as the `namespace` statement does.

Read [more on the using directive in C# here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

There is also much more things you can do with the `using` keyword...

Answer (score 0):

Quick dirty answer -

**namespace** - is a collection of classes that you are naming and filling with classes yourself

**using** - brings in a namespace(collection of classes) to be used

For a cleaner understanding of the parts of a C# program -
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-the-main-parts-of-a-Chash-program

Answer (score 0):

**`namespace`**: A collection of classes. We can call it a module. Although it is not compulsory to put class in a namespace.

**`using`**: used to import libraries in your code.

Answer (score -1):

you are almost correct.
To find out more about **namespace** and **using** refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/) 
Since you are new to C# i recommend you to go through the microsoft c# and .Net [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/) if you have any doubts. Hope this helps :)